# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char' PasswordChar

Tags: c#

I was making a application that required a simple 10 digit password to get into.
C#.
Anyways, I was using the "PasswordChar" method to create my password, but it errored saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'".
My main lines of code where:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.PasswordChar="1234567890";
        textBox1.MaxLength = 10;

    }
```

Can anyone provide a fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PasswordChar` is placeholder for each character you type (e.g. it's typically `●`), not a textbox placeholder. It needs to be, as it says, a `char`.

Comment: textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';

Comment: So how do I make it so that it can allow strings to be a password?

Comment: @NovaStudio strings are allowed to be a password.

Comment: @NovaStudio, you are confused about what that `PasswordChar` property actually does.  @BradChristie has already tried to explain but you've apparently ignored that so I'll try again.  You do not have to do anything to allow `string`s to be a password.  The user enters their password into the `TextBox` and you get it from the `Text` property, just as you would any other `TextBox`.  The point of the `PasswordChar` is to control what gets displayed, i.e. what character is used to mask each one the user types in, so their password remains hidden.

Comment: @NovaStudio I believe you're trying to set the password from code : `textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
textBox1.Text="1234567890";` ?

Answer (score 3):

`PasswordChar` property is what you want each character to be displayed as.

E.g. if the User types `ABC123` and  `textbox1.PasswordChar = '*'` then this will be displayed to the user as `******`. Where as if you set `textbox1.PasswordChar = '$'` this will be displayed to the user as `$$$$$$`

PasswordChar takes a `char` (a single character) not a `string`which is made up of an array of characters.

In your case you want to be accessing the `textbox1.Text` property to get and set the password the user typed in.

Comment: Omg, I just realized all my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
string pass = "password";
```

then in the password textbox compare the strings

```
if (textBox1.Text.equals(pass))
{
    //Enter code here...
}
```

If you don't want it to be case sensitive you can do

```
if (textBox1.Text.ToLower().equals(pass.ToLower()))
{
    //Enter code here...
}
```